# Get the nearest date in the future

Tags: php

I would like to get the first date in the future from an array of dates. I've tried to write my own function, which did not get the job done.

```
private static function getClosestDate($date, array $dates, $last) {
    $interval               = array();
    $now                    = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

    foreach ($dates as $d) {
        $dateTime           = strtotime($date);
        $toTime             = strtotime($d);

        // Do not parse dates older than today
        if (strtotime($d) < $now) { continue 1; }

        // Only do dates in the future
        if ($toTime < $dateTime) { continue 1; }
        $interval[]         = abs($dateTime - $toTime);
    }

    // If there is no interval, use the latest date
    if (!count($interval)) {
        return $last;
    }

    asort($interval);
    $closest                = key($interval);
    return $dates[$closest];
}
```

This code works but it also works the other way around. Next to that, when there is no last date, it should use the $last parameter which is the last date.

The reason I want to know this is because I have a range of dates on which people can book nights on. I want to know the difference in days to calculate the amount of nights they can book. Calculating a difference in dates is easy, but I do need to know when the next booking appears. These are provided in the $dates parameter.

What should I change in my code to get it fixed (I've tried to continue the foreach whenever the date was in the past based on the $date parameter) or can someone provide me the code?

Comment: Why are you passing `$dates` by reference? You do not modify it it anywhere in your function.

Comment: I've tried removing used dates, which caused problems. I've left the reference by accident.

Comment: Just a general tip: don't handle dates as text, it makes it terribly difficult to do maths.

Comment: How should I handle dates in the future? UNIX timestamp will be unreliable in 20 years.

Comment: @MichaelSnoeren I didn't know that. Is the Pope playing again with the calendar?

Comment: The UNIX timestamp is an integer and an integer has a maximum. The maximum will be reached in around 20 years.

Comment: It overflows when stored as **signed 32-bit integer** (even today if you need to store future dates). To use timestamps beyond the 1970—2038 range you can use 64-bit PHP or `DateTime` objects available natively for over a decade. Also, **your current code already makes a heavy use of Unix timestamps** (that's what `date()` and `strtotime()` use). All my original comment stated is that it isn't useful to convert a properly typed date (integer or object) to text ("2017-28-05") right before using it to do manipulations that need to take benefit of the fact that it's a date and not a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem myself. Instead of using the dates array I'm now using the date as key in the interval to retrieve the date again. This does work properly.

```
private static function getClosestDate($date, array $dates, $last) {
    $interval               = array();
    $now                    = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

    foreach ($dates as $d) {
        $dateTime           = strtotime($date);
        $toTime             = strtotime($d);

        // Do not parse dates older than today
        if (strtotime($d) < $now) { continue 1; }

        // Only do dates in the future
        if ($toTime < $dateTime) { continue 1; }
        $interval[$d]       = abs($dateTime - $toTime);
    }

    // If there is no interval, use the latest date
    if (!count($interval)) {
        return $last;
    }

    asort($interval);
    $closest                = key($interval);

    return $closest;
}
```